# How to Upload Multiple file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I use ngFileUpload for upload files but it can upload only 1 file.

I want to upload and Image File and PDF File. How to upload multi file?

Help me please.

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('pageApp', ['ngFileUpload']);

    app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
        $scope.uploadPic = function (file) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({

                url: 'save_form.php',
                data: {
                    file: file,
                    username: $scope.username
                },
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            }
        };

    }]);

})();
```

```html
  <form name="myForm">    
      Profile Picture: <input type="file" ngf-select="" ng-model="picFile" name="file" ngf-accept="'image/*'">
      <br>
      Resume(.pdf): <input type="file" ngf-select="" ng-model="resumeFile" name="fileResume">
      <br>

      <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to upload profile picture and resume both once?

Comment: Yes,I want to upload profile picture and resume both once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload multiple files at the same time you can combine those 2 input field and add multiple attribute to the input tag. Make sure your backend can accept multiple files / support the following features.

```
<form name="myForm">    
      Picture & Resume: <input type="file" ngf-select="" 
               ng-model="picFile" name="file"  ngf-pattern="'image/*,application/pdf'" multiple>
      <br>

      <button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit</button>
  </form>
```